# menu item linked to the most recent element of a cpt

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, menu

I work with wordpress and the Divi theme.
I have a CPT named Publications.
I will have one item of this CPT par year (from 2013).
"Publications" is one item of the principal menu.
Is there a solution to build a link to the last item of the publications's CPT ?

Caroline